# Write text on arrow conneting two nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm trying to create a simple flowchart.
The final step would be to connect the first and last nodes with an arrow and write some text on the arrow.

I'm struggling with getting the text on the arrow.

Here's what I have done:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    \node [block] (init) {A};
    \node [block] (init2) {A};
   \node [block, below of=init] (init3) {B};
   \node [block, below of=init3] (init4) {C};

    \path [line] (init) -- (init2);
    \path [line] (init2) -- (init3);
    \path [line] (init3) -- (init4);
   \draw [->] (init4.west) -| ++(-1,0) |- (init.west);


\end{tikzpicture}
```

The last line: `\draw [->] (init4.west) -| ++(-1,0) |- (init.west);` connects the two nodes. However, I am unable to add text on this arrow.

Comment: the `auto` parameter you give the `tikzpicture` actually moves the text *from* the arrow. So remove that (I know this is a 2,5 year old question)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to copy those `block`, `line` stuff which comes from a question here from a few years back and got stuck online.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm]
\node (init) {A};
\node[below of=init] (init2) {B};
\node[below of=init2] (init3) {C};

\draw (init) -- (init2) -- (init3);
\draw [->] (init3) -| ++(-1,0) |- (init) node[pos=0.25,left] {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When you have a orthogonal classifier on a path midway or the pos of the path is set to the corner of that path. Here the part from the temporary point to `init`. So pos=0 is the temporary point and pos=1 is `init`. That's why 0.25 works as the midway.

[image]